# Unable to use sonar-scanner with maven

Tags: java, maven, svn, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am new to SonarQube and SonarQube Scanner. I need to use these software for my existing maven project which I downloaded from svn. I changed the sonar-scanner property file according to my objectives. But when run sonar-scanner following error has occurred.

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Error when executing blame for file 'some file'
ERROR: Caused by: svn: E175002: unknown host
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on 'svn path to the file'
ERROR: Caused by: 'svn host'
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Furthermore, I am using maven 3.1.1 version. Any help would be grateful.

Thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not specific to SonarQube. The error is `svn: E175002: unknown host`. This error means that you enter invalid SVN server hostname in SonarQube. This hostname is unknown on your DNS (there is no A or AAAA record for it). Make sure that you enter a correct hostname and contact a system administrator for assistance.

Comment: you might be right about not specific to SonarQube; but I am getting this error for just one user that has no problem getting SVN updates. My understanding is that sonar is getting host name and credentials from `.svn` directory - and fails. I realize that this is an old question but I am getting exactly the same problem as OP, and I would hate to start a duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that the SVN  url is accessible. This issue usually comes if the path is not accessible. It can be due to VPN issues.